# Kernel symbol table mapped into virtual address space - why?

Tags: linux, unix

What is /proc/ksyms and /proc/kallsyms, and why is it mapped into a processes address space? What purpose does it serve? Is it used in context switching of the kernel during a system call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solaris manpage for [`ksyms(7d)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2254/6n4iaov2b/index.html) explains this. The data is informative-only, the kernel exposes its currently-used symbol table to kernel debuggers and/or the kernel module loader this way, through `/dev/ksyms`.

Linux does the same through `/proc/kallsyms`; `/proc/ksyms` - if present - is a "traditional" file presenting a subset of the same data (i.e. it's deprecated).

The difference, as usual for Linux/Solaris, is that the Linux version presents text while the Solaris one is binary. You can run `nm /dev/ksyms` on the Solaris one to get the same type of output you get from `cat /proc/kallsyms` on Linux.